# Fatal error in Facebook.php -- Uncaught PDOException

Tags: php, pdo, facebook-php-sdk, uncaught-exception

I'm using the standard Facebook PHP SDK along with Zend/Db and PDO, and I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'You
>   cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances' in
>   /home/myproject/public_html/lib/Facebook/Facebook.php:49 Stack trace: #0
>   [internal function]: PDO->__wakeup() #1 /home/myproject/public_html/lib/Facebook/Facebook.php(49):
>   session_start() #2
>   /home/myproject/public_html/lib/myproject/Core.php(37):
>   Facebook\Facebook->__construct(Array) #3
>   /home/myproject/public_html/init.php(29):
>   myproject\Core->__construct(Object(stdClass)) #4
>   /home/myproject/public_html/post.php(2):
>   require('/home/myproject/pub...') #5 {main} thrown in
>   /home/myproject/public_html/lib/Facebook/Facebook.php on line 49

I am using PDO, but as far as I know, I'm not serializing any PDO objects, and I don't see anything in that part of the Facebook PHP SDK that even uses PDO.

I know this is a bit vague, but I've looked in all the files referenced and I can't find the problem. Has anyone seen errors like this before when working with the Facebook SDK? Any suggestions what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

```
/home/myproject/public_html/lib/Facebook/Facebook.php(49): session_start() #2
```

This means you have serialized PDO object in your session. You don't need to serialize it in your code, once assigned to a `$_SESSION` it will be automatically serialized on session write.

Comment: I'll double check, but I'm pretty sure I'm not assigning ANY objects to $_SESSION -- only arrays or strings. And the error seems to stem from Facebook.php, which come from Facebook and I haven't edited. It seems unlikely that a commonly used library from Facebook would include a major error like this, so I must be missing something.

Comment: Ok, wait -- this is only getting thrown in Facebook.php because that just happens to be where a session is getting started, right? I'll have to scour my code again. An object must be getting sessionized SOMEWHERE...

Comment: Yes, error occurs after starting session, and it should be present after any `session_start()`, not just this one in facebook sdk. If you are using this code on h++p://localhost/project , be aware that many other projects can writhe to the same session if not configured correctly.